# Test for keepScreenOn attribute

Tags: android, robolectric, android-testing, android-espresso

Given I have a simple Android activity with the following view code:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"
             android:keepScreenOn="true">

     <!-- more views -->

</FrameLayout>
```

Then:

How can I test that this activity will keep it's screen on and prevents the tablet from sleep?

#### Sidenote:

If I set the `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` flag in the Activity (onCreate) like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
}
```

Then I can easily read it via Robolectric like this:

```
public static int getWindowFlags(final Activity activity) throws Exception {
    Class clazz = Class.forName(Window.class.getName());
    Method m = clazz.getMethod("getForcedWindowFlags");

    m.setAccessible(true);

    return (int) m.invoke(activity.getWindow());
}
```

However, the flag is not being set when a single view within the view hierarchy defines the flag.

**Do I need to iterate all views, just to find a view that defines this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched Robolectric sources for this flag and didn't find anything. I've created [issue](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/2012) for it.

You already found the workaround - set it programmatically in this case you can test it. And you can test it without reflection:

```
assertThat( shadowWindow.getFlag( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON ), is( true ) );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and got to know the Robolectric team now has an issue for it. :) I'll stick with the getWindowFlags implementation as it's being reused else where